# VBA: copying data into a new sheet while keeping it relative

Tags: vba, excel

I have two sheets in my excel file - one consists of Backend Data on clients (date, quantity, rate, etc) and the other is a Summary sheet which only lists this information if the transaction is 'OPEN'. So the Backend Data sheet has a column saying whether the transaction is OPEN and if it is, it is copied to the Summary sheet. So basically the Summary sheet has a changing number of rows. This is the code I have for that (PS. it works). This code basically copy pastes the info if the transaction is OPEN and deletes the info if the transaction is no longer OPEN and then deletes any blank rows.

[image: Screenshot of the Summary Sheet]

My main issue is that:

1. I want this code to be relative such that I can insert rows above and below in the Summary Sheet w/o affecting the data.
2. If data exists outside the Summary Sheet, I don't want it to be erased. Basically, I want the code to work only within a specific range of cells (will a Named Range help?)

---

```
Option Explicit

Sub Main()

Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet
Dim Last_Row2 As Long, i As Integer

Set ws1 = Worksheets("Sheet1")
Set ws2 = Worksheets("Sheet2")

Last_Row2 = ws2.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

With ws2
For i = 1 To Last_Row2 Step 1

    If .Range("F" & i).Value = "OPEN" Then

        ' copy pastes the info if the transaction is OPEN

ws2.Range("B" & i, "E" & i).Copy
ws1.Range("A" & i, "D" & i).PasteSpecial

    ElseIf .Range("F" & i).Value = "" Then

        ' deletes the info if the transaction is no longer OPEN

ws1.Range("A" & i, "D" & i).ClearContents

    End If
Next i
End With

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

        ' deletes blank rows in Summary Sheet

Dim iCounter As Long

Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A3:D50").Select

With Application
.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
.ScreenUpdating = False
For iCounter = Selection.Rows.Count To 1 Step -1
If WorksheetFunction.CountA(Selection.Rows(iCounter)) = 0 Then
Selection.Rows(iCounter).EntireRow.Delete
End If
Next iCounter
.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
.ScreenUpdating = True

End With

ws1.Cells(1, 1).Select

End Sub
```

Comment: In `ws1.Range("A" & i, "D" & i).PasteSpecial` instead of using `i` determine which the is the row in that sheet you want to paste in. Eg. *"after the last used row"* or *"before a row with a specific name"* (eg `Range("BeforeThisRow").Offset(-1, 0).Row` is the row before a named range) etc. And then use this row number instead of `i` to paste there. • It's up to you how to determine this row number because we don't know how your sheet looks like.

Comment: Thanks for your response! I've added a screenshot of the Summary Sheet (this includes a named range - Summary). How would I paste the information in row 1 of the named range, then row 2, etc? I tried looping it but it didn't work.

Comment: you could use `ws1.Range("Summary").Rows(i).PasteSpecial` I think. This will paste in row `i` relative to the summary range.